# message: "Invalid value 'xxx'. Entity body should be a correctly nested resource attribute name/value pair"

Tags: box-api

When I try recieve list of folders I get message: "Invalid value 'Authorization=Bearer xxx'. Entity body should be a correctly nested resource attribute name/value pair".

```
1. URL  https://api.box.com/2.0/folders
2. Post request
3. Content-type: json or x-www-form-urlencoded
4. Authorization:Bearer 5iV0.....
```

Answer (score 0):

> Invalid value 'Authorization=Bearer xxx'. Entity body should be a
>   correctly nested resource attribute name/value pair

This indicates that you're probably sending the Authorization header as the in body of the request. You haven't provided any context around how you're making the HTTP requests, but you should look up 'how to set HTTP headers' for whatever language/module you're using to see how to do this correctly.